# How to aggregate several tables into one in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `T1` and `T2`, and they log different types of system events. Hence the two tables have very different fields. Although some fields have different field name, they essentially contain the same type of data. Given that:
- `T1` and `T2` both have a timestamp field with same data type (unix epoch time)
- `T1` has a field called `F1` and `T2` has a field called `F2`, they represent the same type of data but just called differently.

I want to aggregate the two tables into one such that
- `T1` and `T2` (two types of system events) are "merged" together and sorted by `timestamp`
- Has a field called `F_merged` such that it contains `T1.F1` and `T2.F2`

Ideally, I would like to completely merge the two tables such that all fields of each table are retained and have `NULL` for the fields brought in by the other table after the merge. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Use `UNION`. The query below merges the `timestamp` and `F1/F2` into single columns in the result, but keeps other columns from the two tables separate.

```
SELECT timestamp, F1 AS F_merged, col1, col2, col3, NULL AS col4, NULL AS col5
FROM T1
UNION ALL
SELECT timestamp, F2 AS F_merged, NULL, NULL, NULL, col4, col5
FROM T2
```

Answer (score 0):

As you need to insert data in the order of the timestamp value you need to order the data before inserting it in to a third table

Use the below Queries

```
create table Merge_of_T1_And_T2 like T1;

insert into Merge_of_T1_And_T2 
select * from (
select timestamp,F1 from T1 
union 
select timestamp,F2 from T2) as T 
order by T.timestamp;
```

now the column names in the Merge_of_T1_And_T2 would look like the column names in the T1, if you want to change the name hit hte below query

```
alter table Merge_of_T1_And_T2 rename column "F1" TO "f_merged";
```